# Thread Safe Alternative to Thread.Sleep that allows browser activity in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I need a simple wait function that allows browser events to process and is thread-safe. A collegue said never to use DoEvents when working with multiple threads.

I notice that when I use `Thread.Sleep(10000);` my browser activity pauses until the sleep is complete.

Can anyone recommend an alternative?

Here is some code to look at:

```
    public static int f_sleep(int time)
    {

        System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
        System.TimeSpan duration = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, time);
        System.DateTime then = now.Add(duration);


        Thread this_thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        while (then > DateTime.Now)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("NewTime:" + then + "Now:" + DateTime.Now);
            //we do not want to use this because it's said to mess up multithreading
            Application.DoEvents();

            //Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(10);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }           

        return 1;
    }

    private void f_run_selected_campaigns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        jobs_datagrid.EndEdit();

        int count_active = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in jobs_datagrid.Rows)
        {

            //MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "True")
            {
                count_active++;



                //troubleshooting
                Thread this_thread = new Thread(() =>
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        test("hello");
                    }
                ));

                //threading properties
                this_thread.Name = "thread_" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                this_thread.IsBackground = true;
                this_thread.Start();

            }

        }

        if (count_active == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No campaigns are selected!");

        }
    }

    private void test(string this_string)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(this_string);
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        f_sleep(10); //for some reason Thread.Sleep does not work well with my browser loading waiting so I drew this up to create a temp pause in the code logic, but it's causing my threads to not run asychronously
        MessageBox.Show("Thread Done");
    }
```

I'm still unable to find a solution for this. I would think that there would be a simple method that could pause logic flow while allowing UI elements & webbrowsers to process.

Right now I'm using these two for my processing needs, whether or not this will come back to bite me when I am multi-threading... I don't know.

```
    private int WaitBrowserLoading(Control browser)
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            tabcontrol_browser.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                {
                    if(((WebBrowser)browser).ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }else
                    {
                    break;
                    }
                } 

            });
            return 1;
        }

    }

    public static int f_sleep(int time)
    {
        System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
        System.TimeSpan duration = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, time);
        System.DateTime then = now.Add(duration);

        while (then > DateTime.Now)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        return 1;

    }
```

Comment: Wait on what? Are you going to wait for some task to complete?

Comment: Are you talking about c# code in a Silverlight app running in the browser?  Or do you have a web control sitting on a WinForm in a C# application?

Comment: *Do* you have multiple threads? You're obviously doing your `Sleep` on the UI thread.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual 2010 express windows form application with browser controls. I'd like the logic to halt x seconds while browser processing continues.

Comment: If the browser request is executing in that control, then the browser request also halt if you halt the execution of that control. You may need to post some code

Comment: what logic? can you post an example what of what you have?

Comment: I updated the question to include some logic.

Answer (score 3):

Never use Thread.Sleep() to wait for something else to finish.

If your app is waiting for the browser control to finish loading a page or url, you should hook an event on the browser control so that it will tell you when it is finished loading. You haven't said what browser control you're using, but look for an event named something like "Loaded" or "PageLoaded" or "AfterNavigation" or somesuch.

If you have a series of steps in your code and getting the browser to load a particular URL is in the middle of those steps, you should move the remaining steps into the browser control's page loaded event handler so that they will be executed after the page has loaded.

Comment: Sometimes some pages will report completed but still be performing dom loading tasks from ajax. 

Also, I might want to wait a couple of seconds before taking action and let the dom of the visited page update as it would naturally, whereas with thread.sleep it seems the program freezes.

Comment: Then use a timer event to trigger some action a few seconds later.  Don't use Thread.Sleep()

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure what exactly you’re looking for, but perhaps it’s:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public Form1()
{
    myTimer.Interval = 1000;
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
    myTimer.Start();
    //Do stuff. 
}

void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTimer.Stop();
    //Do stuff when it ticks.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am really hope to achieve this with a simple method call. I'm having trouble understanding this though. Maybe you could explain it a bit more?

Comment: The timer will start when `myTimer.Start();`is executed, but the program will proceed with the next command (-`//Do stuff.`). When 1000 milliseconds will have passed – the `myTimer_Tick` method will be called. However, as far as I know, if the program is still executing (as opposed to just waiting for user input) –the `myTimer_Tick` method will _not_ be called.

Comment: If you need to have a program interrupted while doing something else,
consider BackgroundWorker for safe multi threading.
(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx or 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker .)

Comment: what's funny is I tried going the background worker route and I still got thread UI conflict messages. Are you saying that if I execute the method from a background worker I should be able to run methods asychronously without running into this problem (Meaning I've done something wrong to get those conflict errors with backgorundworker)?

Comment: @atwellpub I don’t know about your specific application, and what method exactly you’re referring to (“if I execute the method”). Also, I don’t have experience with web stuff. But with regards to your question – Yes, you should be able to use BackgroundWorker with no errors. Perhaps you were trying to affect the caller from within the BackgroundWorker and that’s why you got the error. What are you trying to use the BackgroundWorker for?

Comment: @atwellpub From what you wrote in your comment to dthorpe it seems you just want the program to do nothing for a couple of seconds, so what do you mean “the program freezes”? What is it supposed to be doing that it’s not doing?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might work, if you have control over the content served by the browser controls, is a time-delayed redirect. Serve the user a page containing an endlessly looping animated gif progress indicator, and containing the following:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5;URL=my-next-page">
```

This page will display the progress indicator, and 5 seconds later it will redirect to "my-next-page".

Answer (score 1):

Would this help? It blocks your new thread only.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    // do stuff
}).Start();

// and we're back, immediately
```

You may also use a `Task`, but make sure the waiting one does not block other tasks. My sample is the "sledge hammer way" of forcing a new brand thread to start.

Comment: I tried this but because it runs the sleep on a new thread the calling thread continues with it's logic immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you do your Thread.Sleep on the UI thread, then the browser can't do anything, because the UI thread is just sleeping. I think that is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, looping while invoking DoEvents() might be an option, if all else fails. You would need to read why this method is bad, and what you should do to avoid its badness. Specifically, while your code is in a loop processing DoEvents() you should be actively suppressing user input, (reading and discarding mouse and keyboard events,) otherwise the user of your application will be able to interact with your application to invoke menu commands etc, but your application will not be processing these commands while waiting. It will, however, process all the commands at once, immediately after you are done with your DoEvents() loop. There will also be other events that you might have to worry about, (or if you do not, then your application will appear clunky,) such as a global notification of an impending system shutdown, etc.